# How to make jquery objects of array from php response of ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my javascript variable `my`, i wanted to get it from php file.

Inside the `selectAnnotation.php` i am just echoing it

```
echo "{
    src : 'http://192.168.1.58/annotate/drive/image/test.jpg',
    text : 'Suresh and Gopinath....',
    shapes : [{
        type : 'rect',
        geometry : { x : 0.1825726141078838, y: 0.23756906077348067, width : 0.11602209944751381, height: 0.11618257261410789 }
    }]
}";
exit;
```

As, i wanted to get it from php file. To achieve it I made a ajax call

```
    var my = {
    src : 'http://192.168.1.58/annotate/drive/image/<?php echo $_GET['file']?>',
    text : 'Suresh and Gopinath....',
    shapes : [{
        type : 'rect',
        geometry : { x : 0.1825726141078838, y: 0.23756906077348067, width : 0.11602209944751381, height: 0.11618257261410789 }
    }]
}
console.log(my);
console.log('__________');
    $.post("masterCall/selectAnnotation.php",
        { url: 'http://192.168.1.58/annotate/drive/image/<?php echo $_GET['file']?>'
        },
        function(data,status){
        console.log(data);
        console.log('__________');
        //anno.addAnnotation(data);
        });
```

While doing this, I can see the difference in console..

Here is the screen of what happens i do console log of `console.log(my)` and `console.log(data)`

[image]

So, how can i make the proper response which appears like inside the `console.log(my)`

**Note :**

The `var my` is the proper format that i need, I wanted to get the same format posted from php file and get it in jquery.

**Update :**

When i try to do

```
$v = "{
    src : 'http://192.168.1.58/annotate/drive/image/test.jpg',
    text : 'Suresh and Gopinath....',
    shapes : [{
        type : 'rect',
        geometry : { x : 0.1825726141078838, y: 0.23756906077348067, width : 0.11602209944751381, height: 0.11618257261410789 }
    }]
}";
echo json_encode($v);
```

and in jquery

```
function(data,status){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data);
        console.log(obj);
        });
```

i am getting almost same like previous one..

Comment: while echoeing from php use `json_encode` and in your javascript use `JSON.parse` of date then process it based on requirement.

Comment: @SuchitKumar when i do `json_encode` in php and `var obj = JSON.parse( data);` in jquery i am getting the same result like previous one..

Comment: use `multidimensional array` to construct data in php not string and log it without parsing i.e. before `JSON.parse( data);` and see the difference.

Comment: @SuchitKumar I think we have neared.. i am getting response like this.. but how can i get exactly like the first one... http://i.imgur.com/CzlLwqb.png

Comment: the first log is what you need it will be same as yours.

Comment: @SuchitKumar here is my eval..  https://eval.in/425020 first log is the one i did from jquery and second log is the one i did from http response..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88340/discussion-between-anto-and-suchit-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try constructing like this:

```
$Result = $Connection->query($Query); 
$result=array(); 
$i=0; 
while($row = $Result->fetch_assoc()){ 
$result[$i]['src']=$row['src']; 
$result[$i]['text']=$row['text']; 

$result[$i]['shapes'][]=array('type'=>'rect','geometry'=>array('x' => $row['x'], 'y'=> $row['y'], 'width' => $row['width'], 'height'=>$row['height']) ); 
$i++; 
} 
echo json_encode($result);
```

//javascript response after success...

```
data=JSON.parse(data); 
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){ 
console.log(data[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use json_encode and json_decode to transfer your data.
In js JSON.parse

Comment: THanks, i have updated what happens if i do json_encode and decode

Comment: In that way you will always get object from server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Its my first answer on SO.

I guess the correct way to do it would be to use eval(). However it is rather recommended to use json_encode and json_decode as Ninjava has suggested.